# Is there a way to create a new variable by grouping data from another variable in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and would like to make a new variable in my dataset by grouping data from another variable. I would like to group data from the variable EDUC to create a new variable NEW_EDUC by grouping numbers 1-5 as 1 and numbers 6-10 as 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
EDUC NEW_EDUC
3    1
2    1
9    2
5    1
1    1
4    1
8    2
1    1
6    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a basic [IF/THEN statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1j60arf27ll4nn1ejavv3nby4pa.htm).

```
data want; *output data set name is WANT;
set have; *input data set name is HAVE;

*create new variable;
if  1 <= EDUC <= 5 then NEW_EDUC = 1;
else if 6 <= EDUC <= 10 then NEW_EDUC = 2;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple arithmetic. Divide by 5 and round up to an integer.

```
data want;
  set have;
  NEW_EDUC = ceil(educ/5);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a proc sql step, if you're more comfortable with SQL:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select
    case when EDUC >= 1 and EDUC <= 5  then 1
         when EDUC >= 6 and EDUC <= 10 then 2
                                       else . end as NEW_EDUC
    ,*
    from have;
quit;
```